# Visualforce Area home page component not displaying as expected

Tags: visualforce-component, home-page-component, home-page-layout

Before you guys mark this question as a duplicate, just hear me out- I have tried all the steps mentioned almost in every knowledge article. I created a new custom home page component whose type is "Visualforce Area", I  included the page and then finally included the new component in Home Page layout. Yet only the label of my custom component is being displayed and nothing else. are there anymore settings that I'm missing?

Thanks in Advance

Please refer the below images. There is no code in the page named "Responsive" its just displaying "HelLo" with both showheader and sidebar as false.

[image]

[image]

Vf page code-
[image]

Comment: Can you please post your home screenshot How it display ? i think there are no setting more in configuration and try one more time..

Comment: @Nihar please refer the updated question for images

Comment: it seems ok with configuration...update your question again with visualforce page which you have built

Comment: @Nihar As mentioned earlier I'm just displaying Hello for now

Comment: it's working fine for me as i followed exact step which you done..Have you added component to right column from left ?

Comment: I have added it to right column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62849/discussion-between-nihar-and-gaurav-khandekar).